# Javascript Error: 'missing ) after argument list" after a function declaration

Tags: javascript, function

```
function popular_xml(){
    flag_sync = true;
    var texto = '<div class="alert alert-info">';

    var xml_teste = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify('null'));

    valor_total_nota_xml = formatar_dinheiro_casa_decimal('0');
    var total_parcelas = 0;
    $.each($('[id*="parcela_valor"]').not('[id*="$id"]'),function(i,el){
        total_parcelas = calcular_mascara(total_parcelas, $(this).val(), '+', '2');
    });
    if(parseFloat(formata_preco_banco(valor_total_nota_xml)) != parseFloat(formata_preco_banco(total_parcelas))){
        alerta_gestao_ja('Valor total da nota(R$ '+valor_total_nota_xml+') difere do total dos produtos caculado(R$ '+total_parcelas+'). Se desejar continuar, a nota terÃ¡ uma diferenÃ§a de R$ ' + calcular_mascara(total_parcelas, valor_total_nota_xml, '-', '2'),'alerta');
    }
}
```

I am getting the error missing ) after argument list in my console.
The error log is pointing the second line (flag_sync = true;).
Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is probably related to what's before this. You probably left out a semicolon or close brace.

Comment: The actual error is probably in the code preceding this one...

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle with the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no var declare variable for `valor_total_nota_xml`. This undeclared variable (without var) are treated as properties of the global object.

```
valor_total_nota_xml = formatar_dinheiro_casa_decimal('0');
```